# New line getting appended at the end when pushing object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, object

I have a select input and input  in my html

```
   <select class="span3 align-right-input" ui-select2="{minimumResultsForSearch: -1}" ng-model="info.otherUse" ng-init="info.otherUse=lists.primaryFunctions[0].typeName">
            <option ng-repeat="list in lists.primaryFunctions">
                {{list.typeName}}
                </<option>

          </select>

   <input type="number" name="otherGfa" ng-model="info.otherGfa" />
```

In my controller i am trying to push this into an array of objects like this.

```
 $scope.otheruses.push({'use':$scope.info.otherUse,'gfa':$scope.info.otherGfa});
```

When i do console log of this other uses.This is what i get

> […]
>   0: {…}
>   gfa: 40
>   use: "\n                    Ambulatory Surgical Center\n                    \n\n              "
>   **proto**: Object { … }
>   length: 1
>   **proto**: Array []

I am not able to figure out why those new line charecters \n are getting appended.This is causing problem when I am displaying it in my view so i want to get rid of them.

Thanks in advance :-) :-)

Comment: When you do not specify `value` for an option, then the text content of the option becomes the used value. And the text content of your options has a newline before and after it, because you wrote it this way in the template.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It got resolved as soon as i added ng-value.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why the `\n` is there in the first place, most probably it already is there from the source field you're referencing. You should inspect the content of `$scope.info.otherUse`.

As for getting rid of it, here's a regex for it:

```
$scope.info.otherUse.replace(/\n/g, '')
```